# How to calculate top frequent value in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which has three columns: currency, exchange that trades this currency, date

```
Currency  Exchange Date
USD       NewYork  01/12/20
USD       NewYork  01/11/20
USD       NewYork  01/10/20
USD       Montreal 01/10/20
CAD       Montreal 01/07/20
CAD       Montreal 01/06/20
CAD       Beijing  01/06/20
```

I need to answer the question which exchange is a leader for this particular currency.

That means for given currency, calculate how many records for exchange
and return only maximum
In other words, the result of the query should be something like

```
Currency Exchange Frequency 
USD      NewYork  3
CAD      Montreal 2
```

Comment: And where do `3` and `7` come from?

Comment: Gordon Linoff they come from the amount of times that they appear in the table

Comment: @OlliePugh . . . They do not match your sample data.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Its not my sample data lol

Comment: Please also suggest C# code

Comment: @CaptainComic Its better to ask seperate question for c#. As already 4 answers are there with postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `first_value()` and `max()` window functions:

```
select distinct currency,
       first_value(exchange) over (partition by currency order by count(*) desc) exchange,
       max(count(*)) over (partition by currency) frequency
from tablename
group by currency, exchange
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0cdf69755c886b86ad959d554389d090).
Results:

```
> currency | exchange    | frequency
> :------- | :---------- | --------:
> CAD      | Montreal    |         2
> USD      | NewYork     |         3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the most common rows in an aggregation query, then use window functions:

```
select ce.*
from (select currency, exchange, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by currency order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by currency, exchange
     ) ce
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  In the event of ties, this returns all maximum values.  If you want just one, then use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.

EDIT:

In Postgres (which was added after I answered), you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (currency) exchange, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by currency, exchange
order by currency, count(*) desc;
```

Note that this does not return duplicates if there are ties.

Answer (score 2):

You could use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select currency, exchange, count(*) frequency,
        rank() over(partition by currency order by count(*) desc) rn
    from mytable
    group by currency, exchange
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `distinct on` in scenario. Simply take count by grouping
`currency` and `exchange` and ordering by `currency` and `count` descending.
So the query will be like below:

```
select
distinct on (currency)
currency,
exchange,
count(*)
from table1
group by 1,2
order by 1,3 desc
```